# Conditional formatting / customization of footer in trac wiki

Tags: css, trac

Is it possible to customize trac 1.0 such that the last modified link at the bottom ( & subsequently-linked page history ) for each page is hidden…unless an admin/authenticated user is logged in? If so, how would I go about making that customization?

Comment: [Ticket 11263](https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11263) is relevant. You're request can be implemented using `ITemplateStreamFilter` or `IRequestFilter`. I'll put together an example.

Answer (score 0):

With Trac 1.4 dropping support for `ITemplateStreamFilter`, the recommendation is to do interface modifications using JavaScript. You can place a JavaScript file in your site or shared `htdocs` directory and add the script to every page using SiteHtml customization. See [Trac interface customization](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#SiteAppearance) for more details.

You can restrict adding the JavaScript by adding a conditional check when adding the `link` element. For example:

```
<link py:if="'TRAC_ADMIN' in perm" ... />
```

or

```
<link py:if="req.authname == 'anonymous'" ... />
```